# Времяшко/времешко

Tags: орфография, словообразование, существительные, неологизмы

Как правильно?

> Всё врем**я**шко/врем**е**шко я это делал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Правильный* принцип словообразования понятен:
се́мя — се́мечко, вы́мя — вы́мечко, стре́мя — стре́мечко, вре́мя — вре́мечко.

Но если бы пришлось выбирать, то я бы предпочла уменьшительно-ласкательный вариант с **ю**, схожий с образованием других слов среднего рода (они также имеют два слога, первый — ударный):
мо́ре — мо́рюшко, го́ре — го́рюшко, по́ле — по́люшко, *вре́мя — вре́мюшко*.
Такая форма является разговорной, со стилизацией "под старинку".

И примеры есть.

*Время спит, положив мне голову на плечо,

И во сне вздыхает и видит сны ни о чем.

Я его баюкаю, тихо песню ему пою:

«Баю-бай, **Времюшко**, ох, смотри, не ложись на краю...»*
Сборник прозы и поэзии. Лучшие слова — интонации

*Что за **времюшко** лихое настало?* (А. Рай. Огонь твоего сердца).

*Ох, и летит ***время-времюшко***, растут чужие дети быстро. Не поспеешь!* (Е. Хамуляк. Слеза Зари).

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта режут слух.  И дело не в искусственности новоизобретённых слов "времяшко" и "времешко".  Даже с часто используемым словом "времечко" эта фраза не очень хороша.

Может, лучше написать "Я так делал отродясь." ?

Comment: Записать-то можно, вариантов много. Да только цель вопроса другая.  Вот есть просторечное выражение тирешка, даже где-то в источниках видела. Есть киношка.   Есть времечко из словаря: Русский орфографический словарь. Времечко, -а; ср. Ласк.  А теперь представьте, что вам надо образовать новое слово  с суффиксами ШК/ЕШК, ЯШК. Что выберете? Вот об этом вопрос. О логике русского словообразования. Попробуйте выбрать.

Comment: @Sharon  Я бы не выбрал ни то, ни другое.  Ухо не принимает ни "времяшко", ни "времешко".  Носитель языка так не скажет.

Comment: Автора интересует не просто вывод: носитель так не скажет.   Ведь суффикс ШК применяется в других словах, выражая определенную оценку.   Вот такое у нас врем(и)шко, так нельзя сказать?  Нужно объяснить, почему не скажет, то есть провести анализ всех возможных вариантов. И это повод для того, чтобы внимательно изучить русское словообразование. Вы и сами с большим интересом будете наблюдать за словами. Вот такая это учебно-исследовательская площадка)

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ изменен.**

Возможные варианты:

(1) *Всё **времяшко** я это делал.*

***Времяшко*** — авторский неологизм с суффиксом ***ШК***, сохранение ***Я*** в основе. Но графика нехороша, выглядит необычно.

(2) *Всё **времюшко** я это делал.*

***Времюшко*** — авторский неологизм с суффиксом ***ЮШК***, по образцу *поле — полюшко* для сущ. среднего рода. Фонетика не очень удачная для слова на ***-МЯ*** , да и графика тоже не из лучших.

Ни одно **из слов на -МЯ** не образует форм с этим суффиксом. а это тоже показатель правильности. Поэтому этой формы **нет в словаре,** как и всех других.

(3) ***Времешко*** — авторский неологизм с суффиксом ***ЕШК***, по образцу *время — времечко*. Графика самая **удачная** из трех вариантов, но такого суффикса нет в языке для сущ. ср.рода.

Есть суффикс ***ЕШЕК***  для сущ. м. рода: *краешек, хлебушек.*
Также есть: *тире — тирешка, кино — киношка* — женский род, для ударного окончания О/Е.

**Вывод**

В каждом варианте есть недостатки, поэтому подобрать безупречную форму для такого слова **не удается.**
Указанные варианты могут использоваться в текстах определенной направленности и стилизации, но это **ненормированная** орфография.

**Для молодежного сленга** в Сети более употребителен   суффикс ИШК (времишко), так как в нем есть характерный оттенок **пренебрежительности.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Все рассмотренные суффиксы относятся к суффиксам **субъективной** оценки и имеют уменьшительно-**ласкательное** значение.

Есть еще вариант ***времишко***, может он подойдет.  Я бы на нем остановилась. *Золотишко, пальтишко* — средний род.

В словаре Ефремовой: **суффикс ишк-(о), -ишк - (и).** Формообразовательная единица, образующая имена существительные трех родов и pluralia tantum со значением **пренебрежительности, уничижительности,** реже – с оттенком **ласкательности**.

Этот суффикс отличается от других значением **пренебрежительности**, иногда с оттенком ласкательности. Поэтому выбор надо делать с учетом **значения**.

Так люди сейчас **в Сети пишут:**

*Диан, спасибо тебе за все, за прекрасный февраль, за нервный март, за игнорный апрель, за странный май, за не наступивший для нас июнь и за какое-никакое, но **времишко** в июле.* (Красиво!)

*Клёвое было **времишко**. Знатное **времишко**.*

*Когда соберется нормальное количество людей, определимся со **времишком** и местечком.*

*Можно просто ники, не трать **времишко**.*

До вечера **времишко** есть.

И даже **стихи сочиняют:**

*Время, времечко, **времишко**, ты летишь как ветер вдаль.*

*Были времена, а теперь **времишки,** Было много дел, а теперь делишки.*

Comment: Мне кажется, можно ещё и *времюшко* (и нужно).

Comment: Sharon, зачем вы убрали примеры? И там совсем нет ударения на И: *врЕмишко* очень даже звучит.

Comment: Sharon, так верните, пожалуйста, примеры (пусть даже источник неясен). И почему вы решили, что это молодёжный сленг? (Ваш ответ я поддержал, если чё.)

Comment: Если чё, да? А это дополнение, если чё, вы проголосовали за ответ без него)  Но по вашей просьбе я верну, мне они нравятся. Живой язык.  Да, здесь возможны варианты ударений, я сейчас уточнила по словарю. Просто ударный ИШК более частотный, но если ударение не перемещается. то используется безударный ИШК.  А какой это сленг, если не молодежный?

Comment: Но в стихах там вроде ударный вариант.

Comment: Нет, я прогосовал сразу, без дополнения. По-моему, все примеры не отсысают нас к молодёжному сленгу, все они типичны для всех. А например, "клёво" вообще характерно и более старшему поколению.

Comment: А мне показалось, что это мальчики-девочки пишут. Клёво да, так давно говорят. Но в слове "времишко" есть что-то современное.  Дети не любят излишне ласкательное.

Comment: Так вот именно, что не любят. Мне сейчас кажется, что молодёжь вообще не скажет и не напишет ни "времишко", ни с другими суффиксами.

Comment: Так у времишко пренебрежительное значение, а ласкательности мало. Времюшко – ласкательность зашкаливает, это точно не их слово. И почему его Лео выбрал, меня удивляет. Какой-то он несовременный, или в Петербурге все такие)  Еще мне думается, что ударный ИШК пренебрежительность подчеркивает, а безударный добавляет ласкательности.

Comment: Ладно. Да, согласен с ударением: *пальтишко*  уничижительное. А в ваших примерах с "времишком" я не чувствую пренебрежительности, кроме ударного в последнем стихе.

Comment: Пренебрежительность здесь  - это нечто. Оно не определяется точно прямым значением слова. Это как бы ироническо-ласкательное значение, насмешка над возможно возвышенным значением слов  и ситуаций. Они немного философы, но не хотят этого показать,  А пальтишком они могут назвать и понтовый прикид.

Answer (score 1):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Почему мне не понравилась графика и фонетика формы «вреМЮшко».**

Звуки  ***м,  в, б, ф, п***  пpaктичecки вceгдa тpeбyют oтдeлeния пpи пoмoщи мягкoгo знaкa (***пью, вью, бью***) или бyквы л (***кoплю, люблю, гpaфлю, лoвлю, кopмлю)***, нo изpeдкa мoгyт и иcключeния вcтpeчaтьcя (***к гoлyбю***). Позиция пocлe гopтaнныx ***к, г, x***, шипящиx ***ш, ч, ж, щ***, a тaкжe пocлe ц нe пpимeняeтcя.

Звуки ***c, з, т, д***  имeют тaкжe pяд иcтopичecки oбycлoвлeнныx oгpaничeний, пoзвoляющиx пpocтaвлять ю пocлe дaнныx coглacныx в pядe oкoнчaний cyщecтвитeльныx (гвoздю, кapacю, гocтю, князю), нo тoлькo нe в глaгoлax (пocкoлькy фopмы cляпcю, cлямзю, пocтю, бдю – пpocтopeчныe, a в языкe литepaтypнoм дoлжнo нaблюдaтьcя измeнeниe coглacныx, нaпp. кaк в cкoльжy, cнaбжy, вaкшy, пoщycь).

Из вышeoпиcaнныx пpaвил иcключeниями являютcя лишь **зaимcтвoвaния** (бюcт, пюпитp, бюгeль, дeжaвю, мюpид, кypфюpcт; бpoшюpa, жюpи, Чюpлёниc; кювeт, Xюэ, гюpзa; Цюpиx и т. д.), в ocнoвнoм, этo **инoязычныe нaзвaния и имeнa.**
Пoдpoбнee нa: https://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/alfavit-istoria/istoria-bukv/bukva-yu/323/?q=463&n=323